# Creating a Moq of a static extension method from LLBLGen

Tags: c#, unit-testing, moq, extension-methods, llblgen

i'm trying to use Moq to mock an extension method from the *IDataAccessAdapter* interface from LLBLGen. Here is *FetchQueryAsync* the extension method.

Doing so gave me the error that i can't Mock static extension methods. However there is no way i can change the code. So i tried creating a wrapper class, yet i had no success doing that either because i do not know how to apply it.

In the method Fetch, i want FetchQueryAsync to return an object i specified during the test and not actually execute the query.

```
public class QueryHandler
{
    private IDataAccessAdapterProvider dataAccessAdapterProvider;
    public QueryHandler(IDataAccessAdapterProvider provider)
    {
        this.dataAccessAdapterProvider = provider;
    }

    private async Task<T> Fetch(DynamicQuery<T> query)
    {
        using (IDataAccessAdapter adapter = dataAccessAdapterProvider.Provide()
        {
            result = await adapter.FetchQueryAsync(query)
        }
    }
}

public class DataAccessAdapterProvider : IDataAccessAdapterProvider
{
    public IDataAccessAdapter Provide()
    {
    var adapter = new DataAccessAdapter();
    return adapter;
    }
}
```

So in my Unit Test i have this:

```
List<int> il = new List<int>();

Mock<IDataAccessAdapterProvider> mock = new Mock<IDataAccessAdapterProvider>();

mock.Setup(m => m.Provide()
  .FetchQueryAsync<int>(It.IsAny<DynamicQuery<int>>()))
  .ReturnsAsync(il);
```

This won't work however because it's not supported.
So i tried wrapping the method as such.

```
interface IWrap
{
    Task<List<TElement>> FetchQueryAsync<TElement>(IDataAccessAdapter adapter, DynamicQuery<TElement> query);
}

public class Wrap : IWrap
{
    public async Task<List<TElement>> FetchQueryAsync<TElement>(IDataAccessAdapter adapter, DynamicQuery<TElement> query)
    {
        return await adapter.FetchQueryAsync(query);
    }
}
```

How do i apply this wrapper with Moq to mock the interface?

Comment: why are you trying to mock an extension method?  what exactly are you trying to test?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You started with an extension method and then you created your `IWrap` interface along with an implementation that uses the extension method. That's perfect.

Now all you need is to inject it into your class, just like `IDataAccessAdapterProvider` is already injected:

```
public class QueryHandler
{
    private readonly IDataAccessAdapterProvider _dataAccessAdapterProvider;
    private readonly IWrap _wrap; //I'm assuming you'll want a different name.

    public QueryHandler(IDataAccessAdapterProvider provider, IWrap wrap)
    {
        _dataAccessAdapterProvider = provider;
        _wrap = wrap;
    }
```

(I applied a common convention there. Prefixing the field names with an underscore - `_wrap` - means that the field and constructor arguments have different names, so you don't need to specify `this.wrap`. Plus when people see that underscore elsewhere they'll know it's a field.)

Now you can mock the interface:

```
var mock = new Mock<IWrap>();
var returnedFromMock = new List<int> { 1, 2, 3 };
mock.Setup(x => x.FetchQueryAsync<int>(It.IsAny<IDataAccessAdapter>(), It.IsAny<DynamicQuery<int>>()))
    .ReturnsAsync(returnedFromMock);
```

You mentioned that there is no way you can change the code. I'm not sure which part you can't change, but if you can't change `QueryHandler` to replace its concrete dependencies then this may just be a cautionary tale about static dependencies.

You have the source code, though. If you can't change the existing class, perhaps you can just create a new one from the existing source code. If someone asks why you duplicated an existing class, just say (tactfully) that you don't want to duplicate code - you'd rather fix the existing one so that it's testable.

Comment: I hadn't realised that the actual interface wrapping the method, should be injected into the class that is using the method. I thought it could be fully handled in the unit tests themselves. This does however provide a solution.